# No member named value in std::is_convertible when using clang

Tags: gcc, clang, c++14, sfinae, type-traits

In a very simple situation with a constrained constructor, testing for convertibility of the argument, an error is produced in clang, but not in g++:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class U>
constexpr bool Convertible = std::is_convertible<T,U>::value && std::is_convertible<U,T>::value;

template <class T>
struct A
{
  template <class S, class = std::enable_if_t<Convertible<S,T>> >
  A(S const&) {}
};

int main()
{
  A<double> s = 1.0;
}
```

Maybe this issue is related to [Is clang's c++11 support reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748442/is-clangs-c11-support-reliable)

The error clang gives, reads:

```
error: no member named 'value' in 'std::is_convertible<double, A<double> >'
constexpr bool Convertible = std::is_convertible<T,U>::value && std::is_convertible<U,T>::value;
                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

I've tried

- g++-5.4, g++-6.2  (no error)
- clang++-3.5, clang++-3.8, clang++-3.9 (error)

with argument `-std=c++1y` and for clang either with `-stdlib=libstdc++` or `-stdlib=libc++`.

Which compiler is correct? Is it a bug in clang or gcc? Or is the behavior for some reasons undefined and thus both compilers *correct*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that it works fine if you use:

```
A<double> s{1.0};
```

Instead, the error comes from the fact that you are doing this:

```
A<double> s = 1.0;
```

Consider the line below (extracted from the definition of `Convertible`):

```
std::is_convertible<U,T>::value
```

In your case, this is *seen* as it follows (once substitution has been performed):

```
std::is_convertible<double, A<double>>::value
```

The compiler says this clearly in the error message.

This is because a temporary `A<double>` is constructed from `1.0`, then it is assigned to `s`.
Note that in your class template you have defined a (more or less) catch-all constructor, so a `const A<double> &` is accepted as well.
Moreover, remember that a temporary binds to a const reference.

That said, the error happens because in the context of the `std::enable_if_t` we have that `A<double>` is an incomplete type and from the standard we have this for `std::is_convertible`:

> From and To shall be complete types [...]

See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#rel-2) for the working draft.

Because of that, I would say that it's an *undefined behavior*.

---

As a suggestion, you don't need to use `std::enable_if_t` in this case.
You don't have a set of functions from which to pick the best one up in your example.
A `static_assert` is just fine and error messages are nicer:

```
template <class S> 
A(S const&) { static_assert(Convertible<S,T>, "!"); }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This explains a lot to me. The "catch-all" argument and the construction path was the insight to me and lead to a solution in a much larger context (The original code contains many different templated constructors, so that the error-message approach could not kick in)

Comment: So *why* does `std::is_convertible<double, A<double>>` not have a `::value` member? I thought it's supposed to have a `value` member which is `false`?

Comment: I think I see now. I guess it is because for the implementation of `std::is_convertible<double, A<double> >` to succeed, it needs to test whether the constructor of `A<double>` accepts a `double` which recursively needs the implementation of `std::is_convertible<double, A<double> >` in its own definition, at which point the error arises because `std::is_convertible<double, A<double> >` itself is incomplete there.

Comment: I was to reply that's because of the implementation, but I'm not at the PC and I couldn't verify it. You did it, thank you very much!! ;-)